# Running an application in your localhost using php

Tags: php, python, internet-explorer, firefox, batch-file

I have written a php script that will enable me to run a few batch files and python script in cmd prompt. The batch files and the python script are located in the same machine as my php script. The php script have a hyperlink image where if a user click the image it will load the command prompt to run the batch files and the python. In order to do this i need to have a .dll file called launchinIE.dll and also enable the activeX settings in the Internet explorer (you can refer to this link http://www.whirlywiryweb.com/q/%2Flaunchinie.asp)

the problem is that the php script can only run properly in internet explorer but not in firefox....... how to do this????

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function openPyt(strDoc)
  {
    var obj = new ActiveXObject("LaunchinIE.Launch");
    obj.ShellExecute("open", strDoc);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you can ask me to email my php script for reference....

Comment: Wait, so are you using JS or Python or PHP? I don't get it. And we'd rather you paste your code here so we can all see it.

Comment: i don't wan't another one spamming me ... so pls. post your code here

Comment: please understand what is [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)

Comment: This question has little to do with Python, BTW. Anyway, I don't think Firefox does ActiveX natively, although there might be a plug-in for that.

Comment: Its called `Javascript` not `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

You're using ActiveX, which firefox [does not support](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/activex).  It sounds like you're trying to run a python script via a web browser?  The simplest way to do this in a way that will work with all browsers is CGI.  This means that the code will run on the web server instead of in the web browser, though, which might not be what you want.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to have a web page where a client can open from their own pc where when they click a button inside the web page, it will launch a python script located in the server and run the script in cmd.exe

Comment: Run Map Location Case Model</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:openPyt('file:///C:/wamp/www/aizat/AAAAA.py')">
<IMG SRC="../aizat/images/run.png"></a>
<br>
<br>
Calculate Outbreak
<br>
<a href='http://localhost:8080/aizat/web_new/5_cal_distance_period_test.bat'>
<IMG SRC="../aizat/images/run.png"></a><br>
<br>
Run Map Location Outbreak Model
<br>
<a href="javascript:openPyt('file:///C:/wamp/www/aizat/B_MAP_POINT_OUTBREAK.py')">
<IMG SRC="../aizat/images/run.png"></a>

Comment: This isn't something that web browsers are designed for.  To do what you want, the user's browser needs to download and then run the python script.  If this were easy to do, attackers could easily make your computer do whatever they wanted just by getting you to click on a link.  Would this script work to run on the server?  If it *has* to be on the client, you could do something like package it as a stand alone program, and then ask them to download and install it.  Another (bad) option would be something like jython inside of a an applet, but then they'd need to install java.